# Find records in one table that are not in the other if there is no record IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on SQL Server and I have two tables TableMaster and TableValidator. They both share 5 columns but no IDs. I need to find in TableValidator all those records that are not on the TableMaster to eventually insert them into TableMaster. If the values of all those 5 columns are identical on both then that is the same record.

For example:

TableMaster

```
 JobCode | Location | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Other column...
>100333    USA        A112    TR      0057
 100987    TAR        A112    TR      0098
>220999    PUR        R100    LK      0098
...
```

TableValidator

```
 JobCode | Location | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Other column...
 100333    USA        A100    NS      0057
 100987    TAR        A112    TR      0098
>220999    PUR        R100    LK      0098
 220999    PUR        R100    LK      1009
 220999    PUR        R100    LK      3305
>100333    USA        A112    TR      0057
...
```

As you can see in this tables only two records are identical. I need to identify those on TableValidator that are not on the TableMaster in order to insert them back into TableMaster.

Comment: If you are completely stuck, start with `not exists`

Comment: Can any of the 5 columns you want to match on contain nulls?

Comment: In the TableMaster there could be some nulls on the Code# columns but not on JobCode or Location. However the TableValidator do not have any nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `NOT EXISTS()` as

```
INSERT INTO MasterTable (JobCode, Location, Code1, Code2, Code3)
SELECT JobCode, Location, Code1, Code2, Code3
FROM ValidatorTable VT
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM MasterTable MT
                  WHERE VT.JobCode = MT.JobCode 
                        AND VT.Location = MT.Location
                        AND VT.Code1 = MT.Code1
                        AND VT.Code2 = MT.Code2 
                        AND VT.Code3 = MT.Code3
                );
```

Here is a <kbd>[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd10b487e1916af8a0ae344ff5a699c0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Ilyes, I will try this soon.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks again.

Comment: @Neozaid doesn't handle the null case you mentioned in the comments though.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below?

```
Select A.JobCode From TableValidator A
Left join TableMaster B on A.JobCode = B.JobCode
Where B.JobCode is null

--OR

Select A.JobCode From TableValidator A
Where not Exists(Select 1 From TableMaster B where A.JobCode = B.JobCode)
```

Comment: Yes, since OP does not provide DDL (all columns), we will never be able to help with a complete solution. The solution provided by me is a sample, with which OP can develop or extend to other columns. I do think the down vote was too early, anyway, am new to this forums!

Comment: If there is not enough information to answer a question, basically you shouldn't answer it. Guessing, or giving half an answer just encourages OP not to write a good question. That said, in this case OP does provide the 5 columns, so no reason not to extend your answer to cover that... of course you don't know whether you have to handle nulls or not because they don't say.